# Order parameter fluctuations in the mean field model for ferromagnetism (mathematical approach)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, probability, spin-models, ferromagnetism

I'm a math student taking first steps into statistical mechanics and... I need help!

Consider the Curie-Weiss model (i.e. the classical mean field model for ferromagnetism). If $N$ is the number of spins and $\bar\sigma=(\sigma_1,...,\sigma_N) \in \{-1,1\}^N$ are the variables expressing the system state we define the magnetization per spin as $m_N(\bar\sigma)=(\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \sigma_i)N^{-1}$.
There are various "unrigorous" ways to prove that, if we consider the case $h=0$ (where $h$ is the external field) and $\beta\leq1$ the random variables (under the Gibbs measure) $\sqrt N m_N$ converge in distribution to a centered gaussian with variance $(1-\beta)^{-1}$. I'd like to see this in a little more rigorous way.

It can be seen that, if $\omega_N(F)$ is the Boltzmann state associated to an osservable $F$ (i.e. the mean according to the Gibbs measure $\mu_N$) then 
$\lim\limits_{N \to +\infty} \omega_N (e^{t\sqrt N m_N}) = E(e^{tZ})$ where $Z$ is the desired gaussian.

Now one should be allowed to assert the thesis (according to some literature). But why is that? This obviously looks like a sort of "MGFs convergence implies distribution convergence" but the measures themselves depend on $N$ and I can't solve the issue.

This book https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/statistical-mechanics-of-disordered-systems/EBD1B478730D420FA380F510D8C3EC65 proposes something like this as an exercise and has a very rigorous approach... too rigorous.

Can someone help me? Or maybe just suggest some appropriate literature about this?

I apologize for writing the problem in such an inaccurate way, I just hope that someone already knows it and can give me some advice. Thank you very much!

Comment: In my opinion, the nicest way to prove this type of results is via Stein's method. There is an extensive literature on this subject (google Stein method Curie-Weiss; see in particular the original papers by Chatterjee). For older methods, look at the papers by Ellis and Newman (google their names together with Curie-Weiss). There are still other ways to do that: via the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation, via the method of moments, etc. You can also look at Ellis' book on large deviations, as I am pretty sure he treats this problem (but I haven't looked at this book for many years).

Comment: Thank you very much! This was so helpful. I'm getting really passionate about statistical mechanics and its intersections with probability theory so thank you also for your book, I'm actually honored.

Comment: I am happy if I've been useful. And thank you for your nice words! This is indeed a beautiful (and nowadays very active) field of research.